# I have received an NDA without mention of salary, is it normal in NDAs? Should I ask that they mention the salary in my NDA?

Tags: salary, negotiation, contracts

I have received an NDA from a company and inside of the NDA there is nowhere that salary is mentioned. I will work as a part-time employee in the company. Is it regular not mentioning the paid per hour in the contract?

Should I ask for a modification to my contract?

Comment: What does NDA stand for? My first guess was Non Disclosure Agreement but then I do not get the question

Comment: @user180146 you are right, but company has mentioned everything on his side, what should I do with this NDA? Should I ask for a contract with mentioned salary in it?

Comment: I'm guessing this is the US, because that's the only place I've heard from being disallowed to discuss salary. From my point of view (from Switzerland), I don't even understand why any mention of salary should be in an NDA. Are you expecting of not being allowed to discuss that? An NDA is usually to protect company secrets, which doesn't have to include the salary.

Comment: If it is an employment contract, you should definitely ask if you can have the salary included in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not make sense. What do you mean by NDA? Is it a [Non-disclosure agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)? If yes, why do you think salary should be mentioned there? Salary is typically in the employment contract (or offer letter), not in the NDA.

Comment: It's very clear what he is asking

Comment: @Atizs Do you mean mentioning salary in NDA is very clear?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An NDA is a Non-Disclosure Agreement, which legally prohibits you from discussing anything that the company is doing during your employment.

You may be required to sign this NDA before any employment contracts are issued.

You should not expect to find any Employment Contract details, including any details of your post or Salary, inside the NDA - it's not for that purpose.

Comment: Furthermore, depending on where you're seeking employment, you might be requested to sign a NDA even before being employed

Comment: I've also heard of companies which ask people to sign NDAs even before conducting hiring interviews. Apparently because what they do is so secret that even knowing what questions they ask during interviews compromises their valuable business secrets.

Comment: Questions - unlikely. But during any job interview I had there will be a discussion of your role, what the company is doing, and what they want you to do - and that is likely something they don’t want publicly known.

Comment: yes, NDA can be a totally separate document from the employment contract

Comment: @Philipp It also happens that they think their interview process is so good and magical and unique that it is worth protecting as a trade secret in and of itself.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it regular not mentioning the paid per hour in the contract?

An NDA (Non-Disclosure Agreement) is not an employment contract. The NDA doesn't include salary information.

> Should I ask for a modification to my contract?

The employment contract (or offer letter) itself should include salary information. If it doesn't, you should ask for it to be included.

Comment: A NDA is a contract, just not their employment contract.